# problem with crontab entry with time tag

Tags: cron

Does the following entry in a crontab have any problem. It's not giving output with time tag..

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/ferret/bin

*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/env > /home/vasu/env.output.$(date +"%d%b%y.%R")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I understood. The percentage signs have to be escaped as `%` is the new line specifier in crontab. The following works

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/env > /home/vasu/env.output.$(date +"\%d\%b\%y.\%R")
```